# Docker - where these will be logged

Tags: docker

I see a lot of echo statements in one the `entrypoint.sh`.

1. Where these logs will be stored ?
2. I believe, these will be automatically logged. Useful in debugging
   to see which environment variables ingested etc .. ?

A Sample entrypoint.sh file
https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop/blob/master/base/entrypoint.sh

Comment: Please include relevant portions of the Dockerfile in your question, not via volatile external links. Also, extract a [mcve].

Comment: The Docker documentation has a whole subsection on logging, starting with [View logs for a container or service](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/).  The very short answer is that the main process's stdout and stderr will be visible if you `docker run` the container in the foreground, and via `docker logs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If `entrypoint.sh` is the image's entrypoint, it'll be logged in the `docker logs` output and in the container's log files (usually at `/var/lib/docker/containers/<container-id>/<container-id>-json.log`).
2. That's usually done for exposing the configuration upon which the container is running. In this case the container is only reporting what's doing, as half of the `echo` lines are just setting up the hadoop configuration files.

Comment: Thanks, can you share some insights about the 2) point as well